# Does Spring Data MongoDB supports MongoDB 3.4 collation feature?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Im using:

- spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.1.RELEASE
- spring-data-mongodb 1.10.0.RELEASE
- MongoDB 3.4

I need to use and aggregation like:

```
db.getCollection('person').aggregate([{$project:{firstName:1,lastName:1,sortName:{$concat:["$firstName"," ","$lastName"]}}},{$sort:{sortName:1}}],{collation:{locale:"es",strength:2}})
```

But I don't find how to use collation with spring-data-mongodb? Does anyone knows if Spring Data MongoDB actually supports collation new MongoDB 3.4 feature? If not, does are plans to support it soon? I could not find anything about it at Spring Data MongoDB.

Comment: I dont think so. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1518

Comment: Thanks a lot Veeram!

Comment: FYI, collation support was later added in Spring Data MongoDB version 2.0.0.M3 (2017-05-09)

Answer (score -2):

I am tried this and working with **mondoDB 4.2** version