# Mongodb error $substrBytes: Invalid range, ending index is in the middle of a UTF-8 character

Tags: mongodb, utf-8, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am doing a query to extract the distinct first letter of the property "titlu" from my book collection, in order to group the books, based on their first letter of the "titlu" property. I have some titles that start with UTF-8 characters, like Î, Ț, Ș, etc, and I got this error:

[image]

The obvious question is: how do I get rid of that error?
There are two acceptable options:

1. Ideally, I should be able to display Î, Ș, Ț, etc
2. If not possible, it's also ok to display I, S, T instead and to group together titles starting with Î in the I group, titles starting with Ș in the S group, etc.

However, the conversion must be done in the mongo query, as I also need the count of the titles. (for solution #2, we need for letter I, for instance to sum occurences of the titles starting with I + occurences of the titles starting with Î).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you should use **`$substrCP`** instead of **`$substr`**. **`$substrCP`** was introduced in mongodb 3.4 to fix this kind of issues, as **`$substr`** work only for ASCII char

from mongodb documentation:

> $substrCP
>
> Returns the substring of a string. The substring starts with the character at the specified UTF-8 code point (CP) index (zero-based) in
>   the string for the number of code points specified.

so your query would be:

```
db.carte.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      preview: {$substrCP: ["$titlu", 0, 1]}
    }
  }
])
```

you can try it online: [mongoplayground.net/p/X6Mo1yEhJoI](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X6Mo1yEhJoI)

Comment: Superb, thank you! Any way of grouping Ș with S results? Or perhaps a custom sort so that the letters order would be A, Ă, Î, B...I, Î, ...S, Ș, etc?

Comment: take a look at [**collation**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/): juste specifiy a collation with level one in your aggregation query

Comment: That's not critical, I can always use java side to order/group further.

Comment: According to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165412/does-spring-data-mongodb-supports-mongodb-3-4-collation-feature, spring data mongo db does not support collation. Like I said, I will do a manual sort of the results. I guess that I could use the mongo driver directly to execute the query, but that's something I have to consider, as using the mongo driver is slightly more difficult to perform mongo tasks.